# Do I need to separate an object in order to give it different materials and textures?

Tags: texturing, objects

So I have a certain object that consists of multiple parts everyone of which has a different color/material. Do I need to separate those parts in editing mode or can I just add different textures to one object?

Comment: In the Materials Tab click the "+" to add a material. Then in Edit Mode select the appropriate vertices and then click assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to separate the object.

Just go into edit mode and select the faces you want, then click the + button in Materials and add new material to selected faces by hitting assign.

[image]